# Pentaho CDE "All" option in "Select" component

Tags: db2, pentaho, pentaho-cde

While a "Select All" feature in a select dropdown component would seem to be a straightforward feature, I've had an incredibly hard time finding a workable solution. I can find three SO questions on the topic, but none of the approaches work entirely.

[How to add a select all option to select component in CDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639546/how-to-add-a-select-all-option-to-select-component-in-cde?rq=1)
[Pentaho CDE reset parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474549/pentaho-cde-reset-parameter/37999391#37999391)
[How to add a "select all" option to select component in CDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213674/how-to-add-a-select-all-option-to-select-component-in-cde?rq=1)

I have a table with a column that contains ratings from 1-5 (as string-type). I need to give users the option to select either a value from 1-5 or an "All".

I created a simple datasource (DB2) pulling in the numbers 1-5 as strings. When applicable below, I would `UNION ALL` with a `''` or an "All"

`SELECT ... WHERE (CAST(RATING AS CHAR) = CAST(${parameter} AS CHAR) OR ${parameter} =  '')`

`SELECT ... WHERE (RATING = ${parameter} OR ${parameter} =  '')`

`SELECT ... WHERE (RATING LIKE (CASE WHEN ${parameter} = 'All' THEN '%' ELSE ${parameter} END))`

I use the "Select Component" and "Simple Parameter" features as would be expected. I've experimented with setting the "Parameter Property Value" equal to `''`, "All", and numbers 1-5, but I can only get **either** the "All" **or** the numeric selections to work. In probably 50 iterations of this methodology, I've never once successfully had **both** work.

Is there a simple or straightforward way to add an "All" selection without switching to a multi-select component or additional JavaScript?

Comment: It could be that when you use numeric values Pentaho encodes the parameter as number, thus not wrapping it in quotes in the SQL, and wrapping it in quotes otherwise. That would be an explanation why you can only use 'either or' (only one type would work when comparing with `RATING`). Did you try to use the parameter inside a LIKE clause, like this: `WHERE TO_CHAR(RATING) LIKE ${parameter}` and then use '%' as value for 'All'? I think I managed to solve something similar with this strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out, (thanks partially to the advice of both @dooms and @Óscar Gómez Alcañiz).

When I pulled in the ratings for my selector component, I forced everything to type `str` so that I could include the 'All' component:

```
SELECT 'All' AS RATING
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '1'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '4'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '5'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Then in the query for my table component, I added this condition:

`WHERE (MY_RATING IN (${Rating_Parameter}) OR ${Rating_Parameter} LIKE ('All'))`

For some reason, using `IN` is not sufficient on the 'All'. The query only worked if I used `LIKE`. As written above, however, everything finally worked how I desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want users to be able to filter certain information on this rating (e.g. a movies list) but when no rating is selected all movies should be shown.

I've come across this multiple times and while this solution might not be the best out there it's very easy to implement and it works.

basically you create an SQL where you select your data for the select-component

```
SELECT RATING
UNION
SELECT '...'
ORDER BY RATING
```

Now add a Simple Parameter 'Rating' or whatever you'd like to call it. And use it in your main query (for which the filter is required) like so:

```
SELECT 'all the data you want to show'
FROM 'your table'
WHERE 'your conditions'
AND
CASE WHEN ${Rating} NOT LIKE '...' THEN RATING = ${Rating} else RATING NOT IN ('dummy value') END
```

where the 'dummy value' stands for any value that would never occur inside your RATINGS table.