# Pentaho CDE “All” options in multiselect component

Tags: sql, db2, components, pentaho, pentaho-cde

all! I try to solve my problem, but I need help.
I use Pentaho CDE, I have some multiple select components and table. I need to transmite my data from multiple selector to my table like a parameters.
I read a lot of topics on this issue, but haven't founded an answer.
I see 
[How to add a select all option to select component in CDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639546/how-to-add-a-select-all-option-to-select-component-in-cde#new-answer) and 
[Pentaho CDE "All" option in "Select" component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925524/pentaho-cde-all-option-in-select-component/52407372#52407372)
I have this code:

```
where (a.Group in (${group_par}) and a.Event_type in (${event_type_par}))  or (a.Group like (case when ${group_par} = 'ALL' then '%' ELSE ${group_par} end))
```

Option when I choose "Select all" is working correct, option when I choose one parameters is working correct, but when I choose more than one parameters, my query isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-select component provides values as an array. We need to convert it in value with quotes. we can write this in post change event of the component. Below is the sample code you can use.

```
if(group_par.length >= 1 ){
    for(i=0;i<group_par.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            testString ="";            
        }
        else{
            testString =testString + "',";
        }
        testString =testString + "'" + group_par[i]
        if(i==group_par.length-1)
        {
                testString =testString + "'";
        }
    }
```

Now new variable will be **teststring** instead of **group_par**

I hope this help...